# In a clustered Liferay setup, do all modules run on all nodes?

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7.1

I have a two-node Liferay 7.1 cluster. I manually restarted an OSGI module via Felix and noticed that only one of the two nodes has any logs about it.

The module in question does not work, or fail, as intended (hence the restarting) and I want to cover all my bases. Do OSGI modules run on all nodes, or are they split between nodes in Liferay 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deploy modules to both the nodes. They have to be active and running on both the nodes. Please check and make sure that you have the module deployed to both and test.

Hope this helps.